# Allow Laravel app to create/modify project files?

Tags: php, laravel

I have plans on making a generator GUI, accessible on a route while in development mode. When taking some action in the GUI it will create or update corresponding files in the project folder. This means the web server user need permissions to handle the files.

What is a good way to accomplish that? I have thought of a few approaches but not sure.

- After you pull in my package, let the user chmod everything themselves. This might be an issue as these changes will be committed to source control
- Add some kind of installer script that you can run with sudo to do 1) for you.
- Add a temporary workfolder for the generator where it has full access. Then you set up some symlink thing to the actual project folder so it stays in sync. That way you won't have the Git issues.

I am excited to hear what you think about this.

Comment: a) I'm fairly sure that source control does not store permission information, b) a webserver needs the appropriate permissions set anyway so what you're basically asking is how to deploy a webproject.

Comment: By default, git will update file permissions if you change them. Well, usually the server is only allowed to put stuff in cahce/storage folders? Becouse of the file permissions when installing laravel. Im not sure about this apprechiate your input

Comment: You can't commit a file to git and have its permissions set to e.g. `rw-r-r` and owned by e.g. `www-data` that makes no sense. When you pull sources from git the permissions are set based on the user you use to pull those sources. if you are using a git package for PHP and pulling via a web interface then the permissions should be fine.